# req.body undefined after post on express.js v8.1.4?

Tags: express, post

I want to make a post request with this HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form action="/post-test" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And then write on the backend console the request.
So here is my backend code:

```js
const path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
    
app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/views/html/test.html"));
});
app.post('/post-test', async function(req, res) {
    const data = req.body;
    console.log(data.name);
    });
```

When I type something in the input and press submit, the console say undefined.
Where is the problem and have you the solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple problems.

## Typo in the path

`action="/post-test"` and `app.post('/createGazme'` need to match

## Form controls post name=value data

Your input doesn't have a `name` so it won't post any data. Give it one.

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

The `id` attribute is used for **client-side** purposes such as being a link target or associating a `<label>` using a `for` attribute.

## Your body parser is for the wrong data type

Forms, by default, post data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You can use the [`enctype` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) to change that to `multipart/form-data`.

Your body parser — `app.use(bodyParser.json());` can only process `application/json` bodies. You need a body parser that supports the data format you are actually using.

The `body-parser` module is obsolete anyway. Express has a built-in one.

[`express.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) will do what your current module does (and still not work).

[`express.urlencoded()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded) will support your form.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

Answer (score 1):

in the form add the name parameter and put a value, that is insert in the body of the request

```
<form action="post-test" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

in the backend you access with

```
req.body.name
```

Answer (score 1):

change form action to route name

```
<form action="/createGazme" method="post">
</form>
```